# Go back to last webpage after logging in

Tags: authentication, history, user-friendly

I need help figuring out how to allow users who login go back to the page that they were on before being sent to the login page. Here is a quote from my boss:

> Sometimes I forget to sign in and I go to a page, click and get the
>   notice about joining or signing in.  That is fine, but is there a way,
>   once I sign in to open the page I was trying to open prior to signing
>   in, instead of having to go through all the navigation again?

I'm using PHP to do this project.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever mechanism forwards the user to the sign-in page should include the original page's URL as a parameter.  Something like:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/login.php?redirectTo=' + urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Then the `login.php` page can redirect to that page after the user authenticates:

```
header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirectTo']);
```

You may want to put in some checking on the `redirectTo` value in `login.php` to make sure nobody's trying to do anything malicious, I suppose.  Though I can't currently think of anything malicious they could do.  (Though you *would* want to include a default if no URL was provided.)

But the general idea is that the authentication mechanism provides the login page with a redirect URL when it detects that the user needs to login.